# Combine async and not async implementations for the abstract factory pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, async-await, abstract-factory

We have an ASP.Net MVC application for our online store. User has to choose from multiple payment methods in order to buy something. For this we have implemented an abstract factory pattern:

```
public interface IPaymentServiceFactory
{
    IPaymentService GetPaymentService(PaymentServiceEnum paymentServiceType);
}
public interface IPaymentService
{
    PaymentSettingsModel GetPaymentSettingsModel();
}
```

It is used in our Action:

```
public ActionResult ProcessCart(PaymentDataModel paymentData)
{
    var paymentService = _paymentServiceFactory.GetPaymentService(paymentData.PaymentServiceType);
    var paymentSettings = paymentService.GetPaymentSettingsModel();
}
```

The problem occurs when we understand that some payment methods require async calls inside. For example 3rd party online payment service method must be asynchronously called through http for creating payment object on their side. The implemetation:

```
    public class OnlinePaymentService : IPaymentService
    {
        private readonly IOnlinePaymentServiceApiClient _client;
        public async Task<PaymentSettingsModel> GetPaymentSettings()
        {
            var result =  await _client.CreatePaymentAsync();
            return result;
        }
    }
```

So we come up with a question: How to handle async and sync scenario for different payment methods. We`v decided to make everything async. Updated code:

```
public interface IPaymentService
{
    Task<PaymentSettingsModel> GetPaymentSettings();
}
public async Task<ActionResult> ProcessCart(PaymentDataModel paymentData)
{
    var paymentService = _paymentServiceFactory.GetPaymentService(paymentData.PaymentServiceType);
    var paymentSettings = await paymentService.GetPaymentSettingsModel();
}
```

So far so good, but for implementing this for all other payment methods we were forced to use Task.Run:

```
    public class CashPaymentService : IPaymentService
    {
        public async Task<PaymentSettingsModel> GetPaymentSettings()
        {
            return await Task.Run(() => new PaymentSettingsModel());;
        }
    }
```

As i can understand this creates two different threads for processing Action, which can cause [performance issue](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html).
Is there way to avoid such consequences?  Is it really so bad to use Task.Run  in particular case?

Comment: Check out the code with comparison between `Task.Run`, `Task.FromResult` and `TaskCompletionSource`. If the operation is long running then `Task.Run` is the only option which provides a non blocking implementation, rest both would end up blocking, since the purpose of `Task.FromResult` is for returning hard coded/ fixed values and `TaskCompletionSource` is Async event wrapping, none of them suitable for the use case

Comment: You have posted the same article that I have quoted, it just tells you how not to use `Task.Run`, but it also suggests, how to do Async wrapping using `Task.Run` in the end, it just warns about not using it inside the method, as that's an issue for ASP.Net applications and not to create a fake Async method, instead wrap it from the caller itself, `Button Click` in the article.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj In my case CashPaymentService.GetPaymentSettings() is not long running operation. There is no need to boost it. So for me Task.Run in such situation is really an overkill. Moreover from the OOP perspective i do not want to change even a single line of code in that CashPaymentService implementation because current feature is only about introducing new Payment Method.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj 
Another thing i can`t understand from your comments is about wrapping method with Task.Run. In case of mvc application and my scenario i have no choice but to put Task.Run inside the CashPaymentService. There is no other place for it. What you have done in GetPaymentSettingsTR method for me is just putting Task.Run inside the method, which is exactly what you are saying to avoid.

Comment: what you have done is correct and that's what is recommended by Stephen Cleary too, what he suggested against was, not to put a `Task.Run` inside `new PaymentSettingsModel()` constructor or create a fake Async, as its confusing, but its fine to wrap from the caller. As of now the constructor call being almost hard coded value even `Task.FromResult` or `TaskCompletionSource` would work, but if there's a delay introduced (as I have shown), then you will find only `Task.Run` is a non blocking call, rest all would block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it really so bad to use Task.Run in particular case?

Yes, mainly because it's unnecessarily complicating things.

You can return a completed task whose result is a given value using `Task.FromResult`.

This is completely synchronous:

```
public class CashPaymentService : IPaymentService
{
    public Task<PaymentSettingsModel> GetPaymentSettings()
    {
        return Task.FromResult( new PaymentSettingsModel() );
    }
}
```

Note that `async` is missing here - that's possible because it is an implementation detail and not part of the definition of `IPaymentService`.

Comment: You cannot put `async` in an interface to begin with, luckily.

Comment: Great. Thank you. Task.FromResult does the job!

Comment: Whats' the complexity in using `Task.Run` add I don't find any, that's in fact one of standard mechanism to create async wrapper

Comment: Only issue I see here is `Task.Run` would provision an extra thread, but async operation will ensure context is released while operation is going on in the background